# Why value of pointer changes after cast?

Tags: c, assembly

Code:

```
int main(void) {
register int rsp asm("rsp");
int temp=rsp;

printf("\n (rsp)%p \n", rsp);
printf("\n (temp)%p \n", temp);
printf("\n (void*)(rsp)%p \n", (void*)rsp );
printf("\n (void*)(temp)%p \n", (void*)temp );

return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 (rsp)0xffffcbe0

 (temp)0xffffcbe0

 (void*)(rsp)0xffffffffffffcbe0

 (void*)(temp)0xffffffffffffcbe0
```

I suspect this is a silly question, but why does value of pointer changes after cast? I've tried to cast to different types and i always get same offset. 
Thank you.

Comment: 32 bit int and 64 bit pointer, perhaps

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first two `printf` causes UB

Comment: You're printing the values of `rsp` and `temp` using `%p`, but they are not pointers.    All four `printf`s therefore have undefined behaviour.   Print their addresses instead (`&rsp`, `&temp`, etc)

Comment: @Peter - Are you sure the last two `printf` is UB?

Comment: no they are not, i use %p in all printfs

Comment: i tried to print temp with & op and it is still the same, also tried use volatile keyword on temp with same result, it always changes after cast

Comment: in modern C, all the `register` modifier does is make a variable so its' address cannot be taken.  In other words, the `register` modifier has little, if any usefulness in modern C.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: okay, thank you for your response

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output 8 warnings.  1) missing statement: `#include <stdio.h>`  Adding the missing statement still causes the compiler to output 6 warnings.   2) `rsp` used unitialized. 3) two of: 'cast to pointer from integer of different size 4) two of '%p expects argument of type `void*` but argument has type `int`  5) ignoring specifier 'asm' for non-static local variable 'rsp'

Comment: note: in modern C, the `main()` function, if no 'return' statement, returns 0, so no need for the 'return' statement.

Comment: thank you, i saw warnings, but i actually want to understand why is this happens and how i can avoid it

Comment: when using `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99`.    Your compiler may use different parameters to turn on the warnings if it is not based on `gcc`

Comment: Simple, heed the warnings, fix the warnings, pay attention to what the warnings say.

Comment: The fact that you are using RSP tells us you are using 64bit.  However, you declare the (c variable) RSP an int (typically 32 bits).  So the first 2 printfs are truncated representations of RSP.  The second 2 are sign-extended versions of the first two (think: (int)-1 vs (long long)-1).  At a guess, none of these represent the actual value of RSP.  Try declaring the c variable RSP as a 64bit type (uint64_t).

Comment: oh my god, i understand, big thank you Mr.Wohlferd, now everything works as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but why does value of pointer changes after cast?

`int` and `rsp` are `int`, not pointers.

Using `"%p"` is undefined behavior with `int`.

```
printf("\n (rsp)%p \n", rsp);   // UB
printf("\n (temp)%p \n", temp); // UB
```

Yet let us assume the value, converted to `unsigned` was as printed by OP.

```
printf("\n (rsp)0x%x \n", (unsigned) rsp);   // (rsp)0xffffcbe0
printf("\n (temp)0x%x \n", (unsigned) temp); // (temp)0xffffcbe0
```

When code coverts a pointer to `int` as in `register int rsp asm("rsp");`, it can lose significance [@David Wohlferd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427206/why-value-of-pointer-changes-after-cast/39427657#comment66178545_39427206).  When converting an `int`  to a pointer, various conversion mechanisms occur like sign extension to cope with the narrow `int`.  The `"%p"` have an implementation specific format.

To be clear: OP's code does not certainly print the address of the original `asm("rsp")`.  (Compiler specific extension).

C provides optional integer types `(u)intptr_t` that provide a conversion from/to an equivalent integer and object pointer.  To save an object pointer in an integer, use those types.  Unfortunately, C lacks a latching print specifier for printing the value of a non-`void*` pointer and `(u)intptr_t`, thus casting in the following.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *s = "rsp";
printf("pointer %p\n", (void *) s);

uintptr_t i_ptr = (uintptr_t) s;
printf("integer 0x%jX\n", (uintmax_t) i_ptr);
```